# accessing values in a map using c:out tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

trying to access a value from a map in a c:out tag but the following doesn't appear to be displaying any value. Here's the code:

```
<c:out value=" letterForm.criteria.map['letterForm.criteria.type']" />
```

anyone have any ideas how to get the value from a map other than using the following code as it seems a bit inefficient as we have a map and know the key value.

```
<c:forEach var="exCovValue" items="${letterForm.criteria.map}">
     <c:if test="${exCovValue.key == letterForm.criteria.type}">
         <c:set var="extraCoverValue" value="${exCovValue.value}" />
     </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You left out the `${}`. Try this:

```
<c:out value="${letterForm.criteria.map['letterForm.criteria.type']}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
<c:out value="${letterForm.criteria.map[letterForm.criteria.type]}" />
```

was trying it like this:

```
<c:out value="${letterForm.criteria.map['letterForm.criteria.type']}" />
```

but removing the quotes (') worked.

Comment: The `letterForm.criteria.type` is a variable which has a value which apparently is one of the map keys. The `'letterForm.criteria.type'` is a plain vanilla string which apparently isn't one of the map keys. Do you now understand why it behaves that way?